# JSONOBJECT with index parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

is it possible convert Json containing **JSONOBJECT** with **index** to java Model using GsonUtils ? or please mention any other converters.

**json sample**

```
 {   "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 6619.87, 

            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 1.0, 


            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1529054674
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "name": "Ethereum",  
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 495.449, 

            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 0.0748427084, 


            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1529054660
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [Json2Pojo](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo) plugin in android studio or you can also use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website to generate model class from json.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: i want to delete this question

Comment: Hey @DerekBrown, What part of this question asked the community to write him whole code? As far his issue is concerned it was genuine which I had faced a few month back. SO do not had a solution for that (try searching parsing JSON with unknown key using Gson). I had researched and worked it on my project. I was glad someone posted this issue and I was able to provide the solution to community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily parse this using Gson use something like this:

```
class MainPojo{
  HashMap<String,DataPojo> dataMap;
}
```

Now your whole data would parsed and saved in dataMap with index as Key and data as values.